# My contacts in Messages are not syncing on my new Mac

Tags: messages, messages-in-icloud

I just got a new Mac and my contacts are not syncing in messages. I have turned off/on contacts sync on both the new Mac and my iPhone multiple times, but the issue persists.

Please note, **not all my contacts are missing on my Mac, but most of them are.** Certain contacts like my immediate family members are shown in Messages....not sure why. When I search in the Contacts app in my Mac, I do not seeing the missing ones. I can add them one-by-one, but obviously this is not a good solution.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I'm on macOS Mojave and cannot upgrade yet because I must have some legacy 32-bit apps. However, iTunes has the sync functionality that was moved into Finder in Mojave (iTunes has been EOL'd, thankfully).

Comment: "...not all my contacts are missing on my Mac, but most of them are...".  This sounds like my problem.  The issue turned out to be that contacts from my iCloud account and Google account were syncing to my iPhone, but only the iCloud account was syncing to my Macbook.  The fix is going to System Preferences > Internet Accounts on my Macbook and clicking the "+" to add the Google account. Then make sure the checkbox next to Contacts is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following method

1. Connect your iphone or iPad to your mac using a usb cable.
2. Wait a few minutes and then open a new Finder window.
3. Your device should appear in the Sidebar of your Finder window.
4. Select your device and you should get a panel like the one below.

[image]

5. Click on info on the top line of your panel.

This should give you options on which things to sync. This method is described in more detail [at this location](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/sync-contacts-and-calendars-mchlf24d4e49/mac)

Comment: Thank you!! Looks like it's going to work. I had to use iTunes BTW since I'm on macOS Mojave, but same concept, yes. I'll mark BA if it works...

Comment: how can I sync these contacts to iCloud so this never happens again...??

Comment: Go to System Preferences.  Click on iCloud. From there select contacts.  All contact information should appear on icloud.

Comment: Syncing the contacts from my iPhone **still** has not made them show up on my Mac :(

Comment: interesting.  i'll look into this and see what i can come up with.

Comment: Any ideas? It's still broken

Comment: yes, you need to get your contacts on iCloud.  Then all your contacts will be available on any device connected to iCloud.  To do this look at this link:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205754