# Sharing contacts with husband who has separate Apple id

Tags: contacts, sharing

My husband and I have separate Apple IDs. We have family sharing and are able to share our calendars. But we want to share our contacts in a way that is easily accessible on all our computers and devices (Mac OS and iOS.) We keep our computers and devices up to date so we are running recent if not the latest versions of OS and iOS. I have not found a way to share our contacts in the Contacts app without constantly tweaking or creating a third Apple ID, which is too fiddly for me. Is there a third party option that would meet our needs?

Thanks.

Comment: I just answered a similiar question.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Try this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418389/my-contacts-in-messages-are-not-syncing-on-my-new-mac/418417?noredirect=1#comment587035_418417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Gmail account. Add the shared contacts to that account. Load the account in both devices (no email, notes or calendars, just contacts). You now have your shared contacts account. You can manage them easily on a Mac (copying contacts, moving from each iCloud account to the shared account) or with a little more difficulty directly on the Gmail interface.